# Particle System 2.93 Instance Whole Collection Not Working

Tags: particles

[image: Leaves not appearing]

For some reason my leaves aren't appearing alongside the trees when I use a particle system even when I set the render to collection- whole collection.

I used the sapling tree generator and I have the leaves in the same collection I instanced as the tree. I also selected whole collection.

You can see my setup in the screenshot above.

I also tried converting the sapling tree gen leaf particle system but the option was missing under the "leaves" object- modifiers tab. There was also nothing under the "leaves" object- particles tab. As you can see in my outliner, there are no modifiers for the "leaves" object.

Has something changed with sapling tree gen? Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? If so what I am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: That's strange because they are on the tree in the collection. huh.

Comment: my mistake. Never mind